# What predictions does predict function give in case of arima model (or any model) in python?

Tags: python, function, predict, arima

i was running an ARIMA model

```
       model = ARIMA(series, order=(5,1,0))
       model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
       model_fit.predict()
```

the last line model_fit.predict() would give me the y-values on the training set (in this case series) right? Meaning, it will give predicted values corresponding to actual values in the training set (in this case series)? Because for test data, we use forecast().
And is this the case with other models as well?

Comment: you will have to give the array on which the prediction should be made. some thin like `model_fit.predict(X_test)`

Comment: but it gives a result without an array as well